# Maven properties in site apt files

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-site-plugin

How can I use maven properties in site APT files? For example I want to use ${project.version} in the index.apt so I can always refer to the latest version without manually changing the index.apt file before deploying the site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it. Just had to rename the apt files to *.apt.vm. Maven then pipes the files through Velocity which can process the properties.

Answer (score 6):

My download.apt.vm looks like this:

```
Download

{{${sitePublishUrl}}}
```

where the pom.xml contains

```
<properties>
    <sitePublishBase>http://artifactory.foo.com/mvn/libs-release-local</sitePublishBase>
    <sitePublishUrl>${sitePublishBase}/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</sitePublishUrl>
</properties>
```

Note: custom properties containing a dot (e.g. `${my.repository}`) will not work. This is a limitation of Velocity. Instead use something like `${myRepository}`.

See also http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html#Filtering

Comment: Append something to the link and add text:
  {{{${gh-url}/examples/java-examples}Blub}}.

Comment: Dotted properties do not work directly, but you can still ask for them from context: `$context.get('my.repository')`